# <form:errors> tag in spring 3 is not showing errors

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc, validation

I am working on a Spring 3 MVC application with form validation.  The validation is working on the server side but even though I am returning the BindingResult the  tag doesn't show a message when validation fails.

Controller Method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "server/{serverId}/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView saveServer( @PathVariable long serverId,
                                  @Valid ServerEditor serverEditor, 
                                  BindingResult result){

        AdminSystemServer server = adminService.loadServer(serverId);
        if (!result.hasErrors()){
            server.setServerName(serverEditor.getServerName());
            server.setServerUrl(serverEditor.getServerUrl());
            adminService.save(server);
        }

        mv.setViewName(".layout.servers.manage.server");
        mv.addObject("server", server);
        mv.addObject("result", result);
        return mv;
    }
```

Form jsp

```
<form:form commandName="serverEditor" action="/admin/app/servers/manage/system/save">
<span class="tableRow">
    <label for="serverName">System Name</label>
    <form:input path="serverName" class="required" /><br />
</span>

<span class="tableRow">
    <form:errors cssClass="errors" path="serverName" />
    </span>

</form:form>
```

I know the validation is working, as I step through debug and see the errors in the binding result, but the messages never appear.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What's your `<form:form>` tag look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem, which someone asked about earlier but I didn't think was connected, was having the ModelAndView declared on the class level.  This prevents the bindingresult from being properly inserted into the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
@ModelAttribute("commandName"),
```

as a method parameter after `@PathVariable long serverId,`

Also can you post more of your jsp?

Comment: Ah, I had put it in there but there wasn't a blank line between Form jsp and the actual jsp code so it didn't display the first half of the jsp

Comment: And I added the @ModelAttribute("systemEditor") and it still didn't work.

Comment: Are you displaying the same view after the POST as before the post or are you redirecting to a new page?

Comment: Not sure about this but my form action attribute is always an empty string.  The annotation mapping always finds the correct function to call based on the RequestMethod type and the path.  Also make sure your errors class is not setting the style to invisible or hidden.  That might be obvious but it doesn't hurt to double check.

Comment: I see you are setting an 'mv' variable for your modelandview.  I don't see where that is declared in your code. Try returning just the string name of the jsp the data is coming from and see if the errors show up.

Comment: I declared it at the class level in the controller because it is used so often.  I also double checked the style, the span I put the error in is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code you are displaying error for "*systemName*" while bound bean has property "*serverName*"...